# Как правильно внести с помощью ввода число в переменную char? С помощью scanf?

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    
    char c,
         f, 
         b;
    unsigned char n;
    unsigned int UnitStateWord;
    printf("Введите код состояния (0 - 31) >");
    scanf_s("%d", &c);// как вместо этого сделать ввод целого числа в переменную char?
    UnitStateWord = ((unsigned char)c & 0x1F) << 11;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Прочесть число в `int`, а потом перевести в `char` :) Или, если компилятор позволяет - читать в `int8_t` с помощью соответствующей форматной строки (см. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) Только это вопрос не по С++, а по С.

Comment: 1) `int tmp; std::scanf("%d", &tmp); c = (char)tmp;` 2) `unsigned char c; std::scanf("%hhu", &с);`

Comment: А вообще-то - **зачем**? Почему не `int`? Откуда такая необходимость именно в `char`е?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В языке С в форматной строке для `scanf`'ов есть префиксы для `%d` и `%u` - `h` для `[unsigned] short int`, `hh` для `[signed/unsigned] char`, `ll` для `[unsigned] long long int`.

Так что у вас достаточно написать

```
scanf_s("%hhd", &c);
```

Comment: Спецификатор преобразования `%hhd` требует, чтобы в качестве аргумента был передан указатель на `signed char`. Тип `char` не является ни `signed char`, ни `unsigned char`. Так что имеет место несоответствие между спецификатором преобразования и фактическим типом аргумента, а это UB. Компилятор даже [предупреждает](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87510bb570ae66f1) о несоответствии.

Comment: @wololo Вы не обратили внимания, что если для `short int` указал в скобках только `unsigned`, то для `char` я указал оба варианта. Именно по этой причине. Так что вы просто указали на то, что я уже написал.